# I can't add Tomcat run configuration to my project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Tomcat run configuration doesn't appear in the list for me. I have the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and the plugin for Tomcat installed. This is what configurations are available for me.

[image]

I tried watching some tutorials on YouTube, but for all of them, the configuration was there.

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in..") after restarting IDE?

Comment: did you click on the "13 more items"?

Comment: Yes. It still doesn't show there

Comment: @y.bedrov how can I share it to you?

Comment: Could you open "Run | Edit Configurations..." and add there? probably it would be shown at the bottom part.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Go File -> Invalidate Catches and restart.
It still does not appear Tomcat change the workspace. It must work.

Comment: It seems like only in a docker application it does not appear. In a simple web app I can access it.